# Different behaviour in MS Edge/Safari for iPhone

Tags: html, css, iphone, microsoft-edge, mobile-safari

I insert the code below. There is this strange different behaviour when it is viewed in Edge or in Safari on iPhone. I expect that when the page is scrolled down the height of the `header` does not change, even if the dynamic toolbar is shrinking. In Safari this is exactly what happens. In Edge, the header and the section change height in order to fill all the viewport. I also tried to use `lvh` and `svh` units, but this odd behaviour did not change at all. Do you have any clue why it happens?

HTML CODE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, viewport-fit=cover">
        <title>Example</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="background"></div>
        </header>
        <section>
            <div class="container">
            </div>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS CODE

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;600&display=swap');

*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    
}

html{
    background-color: #151515;
}

body{
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

header{
    width: 100%;
    height:  100vh;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    min-height: 0;
}



.background{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #151515;
}

section{
    position: relative;
    height:100vh;
}

.container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #CE3003;
}
```

**EDIT**

Just an example. In the first mage you can see the [page just opened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIXHo.jpg). The dimensions of the word example are just given in percentage. As you [scroll down the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQfqA.jpg) the page the black part, that corresponds to the header becomes bigger. This reflects also on the dimension of the word that enlarges as well. Any other content with dimensions given in percentage will do the same.

Comment: I didn't see a width change or height change on Edge iOS. Could you tell us how to find that change in order to reproduce this issue?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, the height changes.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this issue on Chrome for iOS? I seem to have also reproduced this issue there.